# How do I get the value from an NSSArray element in the following example?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have an NSArray so when I do:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [jokesArray description]);
```

I get the following:

```
(
        {
        "_id" =         {
            "$id" = 4e91fd49c7e24cda74000000;
        };
        author = draper;
        comments =         (
                        {
                author = adias;
                comment = "amazing again";
            }
        );
        created =         {
            sec = 1318118400;
            usec = 0;
        };
        text = "This is a random post again";
        title = "post # 2";
        type =         (
            punjabi
        );
    },
        {
        "_id" =         {
            "$id" = 4e8cf1d6c7e24c063e000000;
        };
        author = faisal;
        comments =         (
                        {
                author = adias;
                comment = amazing;
            },
                        {
                author = nike;
                comment = "I concur";
            }
        );
        created =         {
            sec = 1317772800;
            usec = 0;
        };
        text = "This is a random post";
        title = "post # 1";
        type =         (
            punjabi
        );
    }
)
```

How do I just access for example the text key within a particular element?

I get an error when I try:

```
[[cell textLabel]setText:[[jokesArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]valueForKey:@"text"]];
```

Comment: What error do you get? If you dont use any KVC features you should probaby use objectForKey

Comment: What kind of error do you get? What are the elements in the array? Use `NSStringFromClass([jokesArray objectAtIndex:0])` to find out the class name if you are not sure.

Comment: It crashes and gives me the following:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Comment: same error if I use objectForKey @Mattias Wadman

Answer (score 1):

EXC_BAD_ACCESS means that you are supplying a bad pointer.  Perhaps you failed to properly retain jokesArray?

Comment: I have a jokesArray = [[NSArray alloc]init]; in my viewDidLoad. Is that not enough to retain it?

Comment: It is enough to get a retained array, however, this won't fill the array with actual content and since NSArray is immutable you must change it somewhere to another instance of NSArray.

Comment: I think the fact that he can successfully NSLog jokesArray means that that object has valid content. (Unless it got blown away after), so it could be in how he's accessing the structures it contains.

Comment: Of course, the array could go "poof" at any moment if not retained, but (as he keeps changing his story) it's more likely to be a different pointer that is bad.

Answer (score 1):

Put a break at your NSLog statement.  Run your app, then use the debugger to continually add layers to jokesarray.  For example, when you hit the breakpoint, go into the debugger, and type

```
po jokesArray
```

If that displays correctly, then type:

```
po [jokesArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]
```

If that works, then type your whole thing:

```
po [[jokesArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]valueForKey:@"text"]]
```

If that works, then your problem isn't in accessing jokesArray.